# Permission to edit orders, but not delete

Tags: users, commerce

The title is mostly self-explanatory: I need a user to have permission to edit an order, but not be allowed to delete it. I don't think the currently defined permissions for orders allow this. 
Am I wrong? Is there a workaround/extra module/hackneyed solution you can think of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the proper way to do it with

[`hook_commerce_entity_access`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!commerce.api.php/function/hook_commerce_entity_access/DC)

> Allows modules to deny or provide access for a user to perform a
>   non-view operation on an entity before any other access check occurs.
>
> Modules implementing this hook can return FALSE to provide a blanket
>   prevention for the user to perform the requested operation on the
>   specified entity. If no modules implementing this hook return FALSE
>   but at least one returns TRUE, then the operation will be allowed,
>   even for a user without role based permission to perform the
>   operation.
>
> If no modules return FALSE but none return TRUE either, normal
>   permission based checking will apply.

**Example**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_entity_access
 */
function MODULE_commerce_entity_access($op, $entity, $account, $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type == 'commerce_order' && $op == 'delete') {
    // Require administer orders permission to delete orders
    if (!user_access('administer commerce_order entities', $account)) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for that™: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_deletepermissions

Have fun!

Answer (score -2):

In the end I settled on the worst kind of solution. I added a little jquery script that selects the "Delete" link (Drupal commerce helpfully gives it its own css class) and hides it. It's stupid, but the customer is happy.

Comment: Using the `hook_commerce_entity_access()` is the right way and should be accepted answer above.